# ubuntu 20.04. I have skipped frame or two pretty consistently like every second or so

Tags: graphics, xorg, screen, amd-graphics, amdgpu

Hello i am new to linux and i have an issue with my laptop with ubuntu 20.04. I have skipped frame or two pretty consistently like every second or so. Firstly i think it was refresh rate at 59hz instead of 60 but the cursor doesnt seem to lag with window i am moving in [video](https://youtu.be/0aSAO6Ao-EM). This issue is especially annoying on video playback. I have tried changed driver repo to ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers without any success. I have an AMD Ryzen 1700 cpu and AMD Radeon RX580 4gb gpu.

Comment: There is a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-multiload/+bug/1878339

Answer (score 2):

hello i found what causes the problem it was indicator-multiload app for monitoring cpu load and ram usage when i have graph turned on every time it refreshes it freezes whole gnome for fraction of a second so i turned graph off numeric values for ram and cpu is fine